# $.get data prints the source code of the sender

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to send get request to a URL on my server (IP filtered. for the sake of the example `{{computer.id}}` is `1`) - sender

```
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://192.168.1.181:5000/computers/{{computer.id}}",
      data: myData,
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function (msg) {
            console.log('success message: ' + msg);// doesn't happen
      },
      error: function (err) {
            console.log("err: " + err) // prints object object
      }
});
```

(err output is the source code).
inside of "MyData", there is JSON data ([I know it's JSON because when I console.log it, it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA7T0.png)) I read that you need to turn it into a string (didn't work either way) when I read it on my server instead of sending me the JSON request it just sends me the whole source code receiver -:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get("/computers/{{computer.id}}/live", function(data){
          console.log(data) // prints the source code of the sender
          console.log(data['running processes']) // prints undefined
          var jso = JSON.parse(json); // throws an error
          console.log(jso)
        })
        .done(function() {
    console.log( "second success" );
  })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
    console.log( "Post error: " + error);
  })
  .always(function() {
    console.log( "complete" );
  });
});
```

so the output of "`console.log(data)`" is basically the source code of "`/computers/{{computer.id}}/live`" what do I need to do so "data" will be JSON data and not the whole file

Comment: Either parse it as JSON or use `$.getJSON()`.

Comment: @Twisty the thing is that .getJSON doesn't work because it's not JSON for some reason and when I try to not put the stringify it does the same thing

Comment: Then I would `var info = JSON.parse(data);` and see if it's then an Object at that point

Comment: Is your API returning with the correct `content-type` header, `application/json`?

Comment: @Twisty It's already parsed before that

Comment: @AlexD also if I don't stringify it still doesn't work

Comment: err: [object Object] @Twisty

Comment: @Patch if that is the case, then you shoud be able to call elements of the Object: `console.log(data['running processes'])` should give you just the string.

Comment: What does `console.log( typeof msg )` show?

Comment: @Twisty says undefined.
the fail in http://192.168.1.111:5000/computers/{{computer.id}}
when I try to read the data is the source code the err 
in /computers/{{computer.id}}/live
is object oject

Comment: @kmoser
`live:25 Uncaught ReferenceError: system is not defined`
    `at Object.error (live:25)`
when I do

            `system.log(typeof err)`
            `console.log("err: " + err)`

Comment: I asked about `console.log( typeof msg )`, not `err`.

Comment: @kmoser but it's not doing the success message it's doing the err so it won't even print it

Comment: @Twisty still doesn't work it's weird but also if it did work It's in the send function not in the receive one

Comment: @Patch Then I must have misunderstood. Are you having an issue with `data` on success or `myData` when sending?

Comment: Then it sounds like an error with the application at `http://192.168.1.111:5000/computers/{{computer.id}}`. Can you provide us with the source code?

Comment: @Twisty Both, the receiver `$.get("/computers/{{computer.id}}/live", function(data){` in data there is the sender source code and in `$.ajax({` there is an error of object object

Comment: @Twisty do you understand?

Comment: @kmoser I updated the receiver code so you'll see all of it

Comment: So your "receiver" is a chunk of Javascript code? That's not going to work at all, unless the server is running Node.js, and even then your receiver code doesn't look like it's returning JSON data; all it seems to do is `console.log()` some stuff. Your receiver needs to send back a proper HTTP response, complete with a `Content-Type:` headers.

Comment: @kmoser I am using flask but I want to receive the data in javascript I just want to console.log the JSON data that's all but instead, it console logs me the source code I saw multiple videos where people just did pretty much like I did and it worked for them. maybe you can post a full answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research I found that the answer was because of the JSON data, I didn't send it well I should've phrased it in the back-end and send it as type text